# SwiftUI - Avoid .onChange modifier redrawing whole view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a custom `PagerView` that is used to slide pages. Sliding works through the `.offset` modifier. Nothing special here.

This example works fine, content can be swiped from left to right.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var currentIndex: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        PagerView(pageCount: 5, currentIndex: self.$currentIndex) {
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(color: .black)!).resizable()
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(color: .red)!).resizable()
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(color: .blue)!).resizable()
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(color: .orange)!).resizable()
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(color: .green)!).resizable()
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(color: .purple)!).resizable()
        }           
    }
}

struct PagerView<Content: View>: View {
    let pageCount: Int
    @Binding var currentIndex: Int
    let content: Content
    @GestureState private var translation: CGFloat = 0
    
    init(pageCount: Int, currentIndex: Binding<Int>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.pageCount = pageCount
        self._currentIndex = currentIndex
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                self.content.frame(width: geometry.size.width)
            }
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, alignment: .leading)
            .offset(x: -CGFloat(self.currentIndex) * geometry.size.width)
            .offset(x: self.translation)
            .animation(.linear(duration: 0.3), value: currentIndex)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture().updating(self.$translation) { value, state, _ in
                    state = value.translation.width
                }.onEnded { value in
                    let offset = value.predictedEndTranslation.width / geometry.size.width
                    let newIndex = (CGFloat(self.currentIndex) - offset).rounded()
                    self.currentIndex = min(max(Int(newIndex), 0), self.pageCount - 1)
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

public extension UIImage {
    convenience init?(color: UIColor, size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)) {
        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        
        guard let cgImage = image?.cgImage else { return nil }
        self.init(cgImage: cgImage)
    }
}
```

But if I want to listen to changes in the `.currentIndex` then the `PagerView` is redrawn and instead of sliding, the images get a fade animation.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var currentIndex: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        PagerView(pageCount: 5, currentIndex: self.$currentIndex) {
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(color: .black)!).resizable()
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(color: .red)!).resizable()
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(color: .blue)!).resizable()
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(color: .orange)!).resizable()
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(color: .green)!).resizable()
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(color: .purple)!).resizable()
        }
        .onChange(of: self.currentIndex) { newValue in
        }
    } }
```

Is it possible to prevent the redrawing of the view, when using the `.onChange` modifier? Or any other way of listening to changes in the `currentIndex`? Thanks!

Comment: Initing `UIImage` objects in the content closure might be causing it, it certainly is a memory leak. `body` must only init values.

Comment: why do you need `onChange`?

Comment: Keeping references to the images definitely helps, but I don't see it as a solution. In the real application the pager has many more images that will be displayed lazily, and I can not afford keeping references to those.

Comment: @LuLuGaGa I tried to keep the example easy. In the real app I want to keep track of the previously showed indexes, in a `@State var indexHistory: [Int]. `

Comment: For testing try changing `Image` to `Color.black` etc.

Comment: @crom87 you could move the logic into `ObservableObject` and perform the work there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the `GeometryReader`; it does not behave as other views. I found out that inside the `GeometryReader`, the `.onChange(of:)` modifier works without messing up with the animation.

So, the solution is to add the modifier in the `PagerView` view, then pass the action to be performed when the index changes.

Here is how it looks:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var currentIndex: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        
        // See how you pass a new parameter `onChange:`, it has the same effect
        // as the modifier `.onChange(of: currentIndex)`
        PagerView(pageCount: 5, currentIndex: self.$currentIndex) {
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(color: .black)!).resizable()
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(color: .red)!).resizable()
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(color: .blue)!).resizable()
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(color: .orange)!).resizable()
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(color: .green)!).resizable()
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(color: .purple)!).resizable()
        } onChange: { value in
            print("Changed to \(value)!")
        }
    }
}

struct PagerView<Content: View>: View {
    let pageCount: Int
    @Binding var currentIndex: Int
    let content: Content
    @GestureState private var translation: CGFloat = 0
    
    // This action is for the onChange parameter
    let action: (Int)->Void
    
    init(pageCount: Int,
         currentIndex: Binding<Int>,
         @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content,
         onChange action: @escaping (Int)->Void = { _ in }) {
        self.pageCount = pageCount
        self._currentIndex = currentIndex
        self.content = content()
        self.action = action
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                self.content.frame(width: geometry.size.width)
            }
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, alignment: .leading)
            .offset(x: -CGFloat(self.currentIndex) * geometry.size.width)
            .offset(x: self.translation)
            .animation(.linear(duration: 0.3), value: currentIndex)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture().updating(self.$translation) { value, state, _ in
                    state = value.translation.width
                }.onEnded { value in
                    let offset = value.predictedEndTranslation.width / geometry.size.width
                    let newIndex = (CGFloat(self.currentIndex) - offset).rounded()
                    self.currentIndex = min(max(Int(newIndex), 0), self.pageCount - 1)
                }
            )
            
            // Inside the `GeometryReader`, the action works without messing up with the animation
            .onChange(of: self.currentIndex) { newValue in
                action(newValue)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using this solution. Not ideal, but it prevents the redrawing of the view.